# Marking a singleton abstract and declaring method private

Tags: java

If you have created a singleton class and set the constructor to private, what advantage does having the class marked abstract give ?

Comment: you dont seem to understand singleton. first find out what it is and then you can also learn that it is a bad practice to use it, since it holds global state and not testable. Look into DI instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of a singleton is that you create one and only one instances. A class which is abstract cannot be a singleton as it cannot be constructed.  A class with only private constructors cannot be sub-classed. (Except by nested classes which is rather a poor choice IMHO)

Answer (score 3):

None. It's would not even be singleton, since you would not be even able to instantantiate it.